# Solving a Transport Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, hyperbolic-equations, transport-equation

I need to solve the following problem analytically and numerically. Just checking if I have the correct exact solution before I implement my FDM.

I need to solve, $$u_t+u_x=0$$ where $ -1\leq x \leq 3$  $, 0 \leq t \leq 2.4$ and $$u(0,x)= \begin{cases} 
      \cos^2(\pi x), & |x|\leq \frac{1}{2} \\
            0, & \text{otherwise  }
   \end{cases}
$$
and $$u(t,-1)=0$$

I used charaeristics to get the general solution as $u(t,x)=f(x-t)$, thus the initial condition provides a particular solution of:
$$u(t,x)= \begin{cases} 
      \cos^2(\pi (x-t)), & |x-t|\leq \frac{1}{2} \\
            0, & \text{otherwise }
   \end{cases}
$$

Is this ok? Does the BC impose some other constraint on the solution?

Comment: This is fine. The boundary condition does not change anything since the data is advected towards increasing $x$, and the initial data is zero in the vicinity of $x=-1$.